# Where is the difference between these code? Shouldn't output be the same?

Tags: c++

I Have written a program(first one) for an OJ problem, But output wasn't right. Then in online, I found given the second program, which looks almost like mine, but the output isn't the same! Can anyone help me to know where I am making a mistake? Thanks in advance.

**Note: I ran both programs in same compiler**

**Input** was

```
3
5
51927 56551 48919
14433 22446 13324
85506 99376 63634
93997 63631 83866
41720 16645 16267
4
34401 73409 48126
80906 29491 46483
79890 23963 57954
67975 70273 65231
4
17044 82753 40300
30368 51031 96851
10353 81816 19296
94218 83673 18672
```

**1st Code(Mine)**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, f;

    cin>>n;
    while(n--)
    {
        cin>>f;
        long long total=0;

        int area;
        int animals, enviroment;

        for(int i=0;i<f;i++)
        {
            cin>>area>>animals>>enviroment;

            total+=enviroment*area;
        }
        cout<<total<<endl;
    }
}
```

**2nd Code(from online)**

```
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){    
    int T,f,a,b,c;
    long long sum;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        scanf("%d",&f);

        sum=0;

        for(int j=0;j<f;j++){
            scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
            sum+=(long long)a*c;
        }

        printf("%lld\n",sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My output**(for the 1st program)

```
-444446533
1595456521
1292087056
```

**Online output**(from the 2nd program, which is accepted)

```
16735422651
14480358409
5587054352
```

Comment: Try casting `enviroment` or `area` to `long long` *before* the multiplication (or just make them `long long` to begin with).

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem, but can u explain why I had to cast?

Answer (score 3):

`enviroment` and `area` are both `int`, which presumably means they are 32-bit values that can store values in the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

Multiplying two large values can exceed this range. For example, squaring 2,147,483,647 will produce a value that requires more than 32-bits to store. Exceeding this range results in undefined behavior.

`long long` is (at least) 64-bits and can store values in the range -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). It's large enough to hold the value of 2,147,483,647 squared.

Thus, you need to make sure the multiplication is done using `long long` variables. You can do this by either casting `enviroment` and/or `area` to `long long` *before* the multiplication, or you can just make them `long long`.

P.S. `enviroment` is misspelled (it's missing an *n*: enviro**n**ment).